# Move all sharepoint 2007 databases to a new Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2007

In our organization we have a Microsoft Sharepoint 2007 installed and configured on a Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition (32 bit). 
The database had been installed and configured on a Sql Server 2000 (Windows 2000 Server 32 bit).
Now we are in the process to move all the databases from the Sql Server 2000 to a new Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise (64bit).
The new server has been already installed and doesn't have the same name of the Sql Server 2000.
We would like to upgrade all the Sharepoint 2007 database to the RDBMS so that we can dismiss the old, slow Sql server 2000.
Has anyone tried to do something similar?

Comment: are you going to migrate on sql server 2000 or any new version of SQL server

Comment: I would like to move all the Sharepoint 2007 databases from the Sql Server 2000 to a brand new Sql Server 2008 (x64). I've found loads of people suggesting different ways (with different problems) but it seems that the Sql Server machine must have the same name of the old one (which is not my situation) or you have to move to a new hardware but the software (Sql Server) must be the same release and same patches.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following steps:

1. Backup all content and configuration databases. Backup your SSP databases.
2. Prepare content databases for moving.
3. Delete all the content databases.
4. Stop the SharePoint Farm by stopping a Timer, Tracing, Administration service
5. Copy mdf files of an old config database to a new SQL server
6. Attach SharePoint_Config database on a new server from copied mdf files.
7. Run **stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername OLDSERVER -newservername NEWSERVER**
8. Start all the SharePoint services stopped in 4.
9. Copy mdf files of content databases to a new server and attach these databases.
10. Attach content databases.
11. Add a content databases from a new SQL to SharePoint with stsadm or Central Administration
12. Restore an SSP databases
13. Create a new SSP using Restore command from an SSP database on a new SQL server.
14. Delete an old SSP.

Comment: Good answer. I'll try your solution in the following days and let you know. Thanks

Comment: try it with QA farm at first and don't forget about backups.

Comment: I've tried your steps but it doesn't work. I guess there must be something wrong with the steps from 9 to 14. Could you explain better. Thanks for your help.